# It Become Grouping Day Not Month

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to make grouping by month. But it become like this image when different day.

[image]

This is my demo code and [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-card-example-jgyc1x)

**app.component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let monthData of resultData">
<div class="upcoming-container">
      <div class="upcoming-container-title-section color">
        Group Month | {{monthData.date | date : 'MMMM yyyy' }}
      </div>
      <div class="upcoming-container-card-section">
        <div  *ngFor="let card of monthData.bug" class="col-xl-2 col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-6 upcoming-container-card-item">
            <app-card [listData]="card"></app-card>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

app.component.ts

```
let data = new Set(this.products.map(item => item.date))
data.forEach((date)=>{
     this.resultData.push({
        date: date, 
        bug: this.products.filter(i => i.date === date)
      })
      console.log(this.resultData);
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`DatePipe`](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe) for grouping the data by month.

```
private datePipe = new DatePipe('en-US');
...    
let data = new Set(this.products.map(item => this.datePipe.transform(item.date, 'MMMM yyyy')));
data.forEach((date) => {
  this.resultData.push({
     date: date,
     bug: this.products.filter(i => this.datePipe.transform(i.date, 'MMMM yyyy') === date)
  })
});
```

In the template, you won't need the date pipe anymore since `monthData.date` has already the required format.

```
<div class="upcoming-container-title-section color">
   Group Month | {{ monthData.date }}
</div>
```

Please have a look at your amended [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-card-groupby-month?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

**UPDATE**

To make sure that the data is sorted correctly, you must use a different format when transforming the dates with `DatePipe` (Make sure to use a [ISO 8601](https://www.iso.org/iso-8601-date-and-time-format.html) date format because we'll now again use date pipe in the template to obtain the desired final format). Prior to be able to sort the dates, the `Set` needs to be converted into an `array` using [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).

```
let data = new Set(this.products.map(item => this.datePipe.transform(item.date, 'yyyy-MM')));
Array.from(data).sort().forEach((date) => {
  this.resultData.push({
    date: date,
    bug: this.products.filter(i => this.datePipe.transform(i.date, 'yyyy-MM') === date)
  })
});
```

And here's the updated [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-card-groupby-month-sorted?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Can I ask you one more question.., When I add this code into vscode...  `Month` not sort properly it start like this.. Jan, Feb, November, mach, and so.. What should I do?

Comment: @javiens: I updated my answer with a solution that should sort the months properly.

Comment: thank you so much again for all your help Brother..  may God bless you